# Find a shortest distance between two buckets of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, distance, intersection, euclidean-distance

I have two buckets (unordered, 1-dimentional data structures) of numbers and I want to calculate a minimal distance between any elements of the two buckets. Is there a way to find the shortest distance between any number from different buckets in `O(1)`? What is my best bet?

```
Input
[B1] 1, 5, 2, 347, 50
[B2] 21, 17, 345

Output
2 // abs(347 - 345)
```

**Edits**

- I expect to have more lookups than inserts
- Distance between smallest and largest elements in any bucket is less than 10^5
- Number of elements in any bucket is less than 10^5
- Numbers in buckets are "nearly" sorted - these are timestamps of events. There's probably less than 1% of elements in the buckets that are out of order
- The number of elements in buckets is small, but I need to lookup at an average rate of 2k/sec, and periodically drop stale buckets  and replace them with new buckets, hence I want my lookups be in `O(1)`

See why I need this and what I have thought of in the [previous question edition](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40870850/4).

Comment: O(1)? Of course not!

Comment: Those elements have to arrive in the buckets somehow, and you could get O(log n) query time if you add all elements in each bucket to a single balanced tree at the same time as you add them to the buckets (though this will increase bucket insertion cost to O(log n) if it isn't already): Just look up the next-smaller and next-larger elements from the other bucket as you insert them, and maintain the smallest-so-far.

Comment: O(1) sure - but it'll punish your insertion performance

Comment: sort each bucket, then kindof mergesort them keeping track of the minimal distance along the way: `O(n+n/2.ln(n/2)) = O(n.ln(n))`.

Comment: How big are your values?  Specifically, how big is (largest_value - smallest_value) / window_size?  If that's less than, say, 10000000, just create an array that size, with 2 bits per window_size-block of time.  Then on each insert of x into a bucket, let y = (x - smallest_value) / window_size, and update array[y] and array[y+1] to reflect that an element from this bucket was added.  Any pair of different-bucket items that overlap by window_size or less *must* hit the same element of array[].

Comment: @j_random_hacker: What if the other bucket isn't known at the time elements are inserted?  What if the operation is done pairwise among a large number of buckets?  What you are describing is an operation on one set with an internal partition, not an operation between two sets.

Comment: Keep them in one container but tag each element with a bucket identifier. Then sort and do a running difference/minimum but only when the identifier changes. The sorting brings you up to O(n logn). The tagging can be done different ways: create pairs, polymorphism.

Comment: @BenVoigt: From the OP's description, there are 2 buckets, so I don't understand how one of them could be "unknown".  If this is done pairwise between a large number of buckets, my second comment's suggestion doesn't worsen the time complexity *per bucket pair*.

Comment: Thank you for your additional information. Would it be feasable to make sure, the buckets actually are sorted in advance?

Comment: @cdonat I cannot control the order of the events, as those are based on interrupts and are coming from two different sources. I can use a data structure that maintains an order for my buckets, though.

Comment: @oleksii yes, judging from your requirements I think, that data structure can simply be a vector. Just make sure, you insert sorted. Most of the time that will simply be appending, sometimes you'll have to move one or two elements backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt: sort each bucket, then kindof mergesort them keeping track of the minimal distance along the way: `O(n+2.n/2.ln(n/2)) = O(n.ln(n))`:

```
sort buk1
sort buk2
min = INT_MAX
last = some value
do
    if top(buk1) > top(buk2)
        min = min(min, abs(top(buk1) - last))
        last = top(buk1)
        pop(buk1)
    else
        min = min(min, abs(top(buk2) - last))
        last = top(buk2)
        pop(buk2)
while !empty(buk1) and !empty(buk2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let there be `n` numbers in total.
1. Write all numbers in binary. `==> O(n)`
2. Append 0 or 1 in each number, according to whether from B1 or B2. `==> O(n)`
3. Quicksort them, ignoring the first bit. `==> O(n log n)` in average
4. for the whole list, iterate through sorted order. For every two adjacent numbers `u` and `v`, if they came from both B1 or B2, ignore.
Otherwise, set `tmp <-- abs(u-v)` whenever `tmp > abs(u-v)`. 
Thus, `tmp` is the minimal distance so far, within adjacent numbers.
The final `tmp` is answer. `==> O(n)`

in total: `==> O(n log n)` in average

Answer (score 1):

O(1) is of course not possible.

Some pseudo code, that I'd use as a starting point:

```
sort(B1)
sort(B2)

i1 = 0
i2 = 0

mindist = MAX_INT

// when one of the buckets is empty, we'll simply return MAX_INT.
while(i1 < B1.size() && i2 < B2.size())
    t = B1[i1] - B2[i2]
    mindist = min(mindist, abs(t))
    if t > 0 
        i2 ++
    else
        i1 ++

return mindist
```

At least that is O(n log n), because it is dominated by the sorting at the beginning. If your buckets already are sorted, you can have O(n).

**Edit:**

After the new information, that the elements are almost sorted, I'd propose to actually sort them on insert. Insertion sort with its binary search is not the best for that situation. Just append the new element and swap it forward until it fits. Usually it will be no swaps and for the 1%, where you need swaps, 99% of the time it will be only one. The worst case complexity is O(n), but the average will almost be O(1).

If you consider to precalculate `mindist` for all pairs of buckets, you'd have to store `i1` and `i2` and `mindist`. Let's say `B1` is the bucket, where you append a new element. You sort it in and reduce `i2` until it is either `0` or `B2[i2] < B1[i1]`. Since the elements are timestamps, that will be at most one step most of the time. Then you run the while loop again, which usually will only a single step as well. So the computational complexity is O(k) for k buckets and the memory complexity is O(k^2).

Answer (score 1):

Create a bitvector of 10^5 elements for each bucket. Keep track of the min distance (initially 10^5 until both buckets are nonempty).

Now, say you're adding an element x to one of the buckets. Do the following:

```
1. Set the bit x of the same bucket.
2. Check whether the other bitvector has any set elements within min_distance-1 of x
3. Update min_distance as appropriate
```

Running time: On inserting it's O(min_distance), which is technically O(1) since min_distance is capped. On polling it's O(1) since you're just returning min_distance.

*edit* If the elements aren't capped at 10^5 but just the distance between the min and the max is, this will need to be modified but will still work. I can detail the necessary changes if this matters.

Comment: The number of elements is capped at ~ 10^5. Can you please explain how would you do number [2]? Is it `abs (bv1 - bv2)` of some sort?

Comment: @oleksii Say you put element x in bucket_A, then: for(i = x - minsize + 1, i <= x + minsize -1, i++), check if bitvector_B[i] is set. If it is, you've found an element in B closer to x than your previous minimum size. There may be multiple in the range, so check all candidates and keep the smallest.

Comment: One efficiency you can use in the beginning in the above example: If |B| < 2*minsize, then check the elements of B instead of the bitvector. This saves you from checking large swathes of the bitvector early on while minsize is big and B is small.

Comment: You'd have to store that bitvector for every pair of buckets and keep it up to date. That increases the input complexity to O(k) with k being the number of buckets. The memory complexity is of course O(l * k^2) with l being the size of the bitvectors. The alternative is to build the bitvectors on demand. Then you'll have to insert all elements of both buckets, before you know min_distance. That is O(n) of course.

Comment: @cdonat he has two buckets, so one pair.

Comment: @cdonat also, you store one bitvector per bucket, only the min value is per pair.

Comment: @DaveGalvin He never said, that there are only two buckets in the whole programm, just this function should handle only two of them. So then you'll have to add the insert effort to the complexity and that is O(n).

Comment: @DaveGalvin OK, yes, you only need one bitvector per bucket. Then the memory complexity is O(l*k).

Comment: @cdonat the size of the bitvectors is fixed because the size of the values is fixed at 10^5, so memory only grows with the number of buckets at O(k).

Comment: @DaveGalvin the values are not limited to 10^5, just the deltas are. The values are timestamps. In case of 32 bit timestamps, the bitmap is 512MB for every bucket. BTW. You still have memory requirements for every pair of buckets. Those grow at O(k^2). With only a few buckets, that is shadowed by the bitvectors, but will eventually outfrow them.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your buckets into two Y-fast tries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie). Search for nearest successor or predecessor are `O(log log M)`, where `M` is the range (actually the max element, but we can offset), which in your case would cap at around four operations.

Since you'll store the nearest difference, lookup would be `O(1)` (unless you get the full buckets each time rather than continually updating), while insertion, deletion and update per element would be `O(log log M)`.

Comment: Building the trees is O(n log log M)

Comment: @Ripi2 that's correct. Since `M` and `n` are capped at `10^5`, `log n ≈ 16`, whereas `log log M ≈ 4`, that would be a log factor faster than `n log n`.

Answer (score 0):

I like Dave Galvin idea, slightly modified:

Let maxV be the maximum number of elements maxV=max(bucket1.size, bucket2.size)

1. Build two arrays, each of size maxV. Fill them:

```
for (j=0 to bucket1.size)
    array1(bucket1(j)) = bucket1(j)
for (j=0 to bucket2.size)
        array2(bucket2(j)) = bucket1(j)
```

Arrays are now sorted. The rest of elements in arrays are 0.

2. Now use two iterators, one for each array:

```
it1 = array1.begin
it2 = array2.begin
while (it1 == 0)
   ++it1
while (it2 == 0)
   ++it2
minDist = abs(it1-it2)
while (it1 != array1.end && it2 != array2.end)
{   //advance until overpass the other
    while (it1 <= it2 && it1 != array1.end)
        ++it1
        if (it1 > 0)
            check minDist between it1, it2
    while (it2 <= it1 && it2 != array2.end)
        ++it2
        if (it2 > 0)
            check minDist between it1, it2
    if (it1 = it2)
        //well, minDist = 0
        return now
}
```

Step 1 is O(n). Step 2 is also O(n). I don't know if this is more efficent or not than sorting the buckets for large or short buckets.

Comment: 1. `mavV` has to be the maximum of the values, not the sizes. Otherwise `array1(bucket1(j)) will fail. You need another O(n) loop to determine that. 2. The buckets might contain 0s. How do you distinguish them from empty elements of your arrays? 3. The last step is O(maxV), which is not dependent on n (the number of elements) , but on the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider precomputing the answer for each number in both lists and storing them as an array.   Use the subscript of each number in the list, and use that to subscript to the position in the array that contains the difference.

That gives O(1) lookup.